# Block rearrangment with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have this HTML code  http://jsfiddle.net/tbpqT/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        Block A
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       Block B
    </div>
</div>
```

When the screensize gets very small, I get Block A above Block B. What I actually would like is to have is Block B on top of Block A while keeping the original order for Medium+ screens.

One of my ideas was to make a copy of "Block B" before "Block A" and make it visible for small sizes while hiding the second version of "Block B". I feel this is too cumbersome. Perhaps there is a more elegant way to achieve this effect ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pull and push

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
       Block B
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        Block A
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wdrjx/
Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering